# Inno Setup Change default installation folder not to point to Program Files

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I am trying to create a setup file with Inno Setup.

I do not know yet how to predefine an installation folder.

By default is `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Then in

```
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp
```

It can be defined a name for for the folder.

So my question how to change it to other location like `C:` for example. Then you do not have to browse.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, you set the [`DefaultDirName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_defaultdirname) to the path you want:

```
DefaultDirName=C:\MyApp
```

Though in general it's a bad practice to hard-code the path, as you have no guarantee that the path exists on the user's machine.

At least, consider using `{sd}` constant (system drive), which typically expands to `C:`.

```
DefaultDirName={sd}\MyApp
```

---

Note that the default applies to the initial installation only. When upgrading (installing over an existing installation), the path of the existing installation is used (unless overridden by [`UsePreviousAppDir=no`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_usepreviousappdir))

So to test your new default, you have to uninstall any existing installation first.